# How to create a image of a HDD without the unallocated space?

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox, dd, disk-image, vdi

I need to convert this HDD  containing a Windows installation to a *.vdi in order to create a bootable *.img WITHOUT the unallocated space.

[image: this HDD]

```
Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *      2048    718847    716800  350M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT    
/dev/sdb2       718848 105582591 104863744   50G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

However using `VBoxManage convertfromraw /dev/sdb2` creates a vdi of dynamic size but with an unchangeable maximum of 223 GB. `VBoxManage modifyhd --resize` can't reduce size at all, `VBoxManage modifymedium --compact` also doesn't change it. Writing zeroes with sdelete as suggested frequently is not applicable since it's unallocated space.

Using `dd` as suggested [in this thread on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/281628/combine-partitions-to-one-disk-image), by creating two images and combining them later, results in a non-bootable image.

So how to exclude that unallocated space of the source HDD?

Comment: Do you have space to store a ~50.35 GiB image? If so, you could use `dd` to image the first ~50.35 GiB of the disk, and create a VDI from that. You need to take all data from the beginning of the disk to the end of partition 2... i.e: 105,582,591 sectors or (typically x512) 54,058,286,592 bytes - `dd if=/dev/sdb of=image.dd bs=4M count=54058286592 iflag=count_bytes`

Comment: Thank you attie for your help! I didn't think of going down the dd road. As to your suggestion the only flag I used was count=10582591 since setting the blocksize parameter to 4M doubled the resulting image's size. Feel free to paste your post as answer and I'll mark it as solved. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the partitions are both at the front of the disk, you could just image that portion of the disk.

Try using `dd`:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb of=image.dd bs=4M count=54058286592 iflag=count_bytes
```

Here, `count` is equal to the number of bytes to be imaged - parition 2's end, ×512 (size of a sector).

To then allow a larger block size (increase transfer rate), you must indicate that your `count` argument is in "*bytes*" and not "*input blocks*" (as it would be by default) - use `iflag=count_bytes`.

Comment: Clean, simple, and works perfectly. Thank you. Just make slightly larger than the used disk space (presuming used space at front of the disk's blocks).